# Calling the then method from within the same Promise object caused the promise pending forever

Tags: javascript, promise

Run the following code snippet in DevTools, you can see that the Promise is forever pending.

```js
(function () {
    const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
    }).then((value) => {
        console.log(value, p);
        return p.then((value) => {
            console.log('inner', value);
            return 2
        });
    }).then((value) => {
        console.log('outer', value);
        return 3;
    });
    window.p = p;
})();
```

So, anyone knows how to explain this? Is there any equivalent usage in the non-Promise world? Thanks.

Comment: Your `inner` code waits for the whole promise chain to resolve but your whole promise chain waits on the `inner` code to resolve. You've created a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Why in the world would you do this?  This just looks like a wrong way to use promises.  Perhaps you don't realize that `p` is the result of `new Promise().then().then()` so it doesn't resolve until that whole chain has resolved.  But that whole chain can't ever resolve until `p` resolves.

Comment: ***So, anyone knows how to explain this?***.  Well, to be blunt, there is no practical use to this code since it's just a deadlock.  It's like two people that say they'll each call the other on the phone, but only after the other one calls them first.  So, they both just sit there forever waiting for the other to call.  It's a deadlock - never resolved.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know it's an abnormal usage of Promise and the usage above is a simplified version of a complex Promise chain in the real world. It's not so obvious until I simplified it. I asked this question because have never realized that Promise can be used like this, just for curious and looking for a better explanation. BTW, Your analogy is very appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, anyone knows how to explain this?

Well, `p` will resolve once the `return 3` happens. But before that can happen, the previous `.then`'s need to complete. And you've set it up so the middle part can not complete resolve until `p` resolves.

In short: `p` can't resolve until after `p` resolves. Thus it never resolves.